# Crystal Reports/Sql Server displaying days of the month and hours

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am wanting to display Employees as rows and Days for a given month as columns. The data will be hours the employee was on call for each day.
Currently my EmployeeTime table holds a start date/time and a end date/date. Sample data would be:

```
EmployeeID StartTime EndTime
1, 01/07/2010 08:00, 02/07/2010 01:00
1, 04/07/2010 08:00, 06/07/2010 01:00
2, 01/07/2010 23:00, 02/07/2010 10:00
```

The report would display as:

```
EmployeeID, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.....
1, 16, 1, 0, 16, 24, 1, 0
2, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Not sure if I should have SQL Server doing the work or using some sort of cross tab in Crystal Reports.

Greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the date difference between the start and end date in either SQL or Crystal - I suggest using SQLServer's `datediff` function.

If you are using SQLServer 2005 onwards then you can use the `pivot` command to transform the dataset to have day columns and employee rows - but some months will have fewer days, and therefore fewer columns than others.

Instead, I recommend using Crystal's crosstab functionality:

- Insert a crosstab.
- Add the Employee ID to the Rows.
- Add the Start Time to the Columns, and set the group options for the column so that the column will be printed `for each day`.
- Add the derived time duration field to the Summarised Fields - the summary operation should default to `Sum of`.

Note that this method of summarising on-call time will assign all time on-call to the day that the employee's shift started - so if, for example, a shift ran from 01/07/2010 08:00 to 02/07/2010 01:00, this would show as 5 hours on 01/07/2010, not for 4 hours on 01/07/2010 and 1 hour on 02/07/2010.